# postgre group by having

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like that

```
select c.travelandsmile_id, c.name, c.surname
from customer c
where c.travelandsmile_id in
      (
        select s.travelandsmile_id
        from spent_kilometers s
        group by travelandsmile_id
        having count(s.kilometers)=1
      )
```

I want to select the records that are shown only once in the table `spent_kilometers` and where kilometers is greater than 30. But when I add `where s.kilometers > 30`, the result is wrong and more tuples appear according to first query.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
select travelandsmile_id, c.name, c.surname
from
    customer c
    inner join
    spent_kilometers s using (travelandsmile_id)
where s.kilometers > 30
group by travelandsmile_id, c.name, c.surname
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly you want find all customers who have one record in `spent_kilometers` and this record must have the constraint `s.kilometers > 30`.

This can be done with the following SQL.

```
select c.travelandsmile_id, c.name, c.surname
from customer c
where c.travelandsmile_id in 
     ( /* find all customers that have only one record in spent_kilometers */
        select c.travelandsmile_id
        from spent_kilometers s
        group by travelandsmile_id having count(travelandsmile_id) = 1
    )
 and c.travelandsmile_id in 
     ( /* find all customers that have s.kilometers > 30 */
        select c.travelandsmile_id
        from spent_kilometers s
        where s.kilometers > 30
    );
```